# Import discord.py выдает ошибку "ModuleNotFoundError"

Tags: python, discord.py, pip

Работаю над проектом, в котором нужно будет распаковать архив со всеми данными и все будет работать, без установки пакетов пользователем. Дошел до создания дискорд бота, но он выдает ошибку, не пойму связанную с чем.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Путь\Папка проекта\bot.py", line 2, in <module>
    import modules.discord
  File "Путь\Папка проекта\modules\discord\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .client import Client
  File "Путь\Папка проекта\modules\discord\client.py", line 33, in <module>
    import aiohttp
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aiohttp'
```

До этого скачивал pythonping абсолютно также и при импорте ошибок не было.
Скачивал вот так:

```
pip install --target="Путь\Папка проекта\modules" pythonping
pip install --target="Путь\Папка проекта\modules" discord.py
```

Папка куда скачивалось выглядит вот так (изначально она была пустая):

[image: Папка modules]

Если в этом же файле закоменчу импорт дискорда, и добавлю pythonping, то все отработает без ошибок.

```
from modules.pythonping import ping
#import modules.discord
import botinfo

print(botinfo.BotTag)
```

Comment: Доп инфа
`python --version       Python 3.8.2` и `pip --version    pip 21.0.1`

Comment: пробовал перетащить папку с aiohttp в тогда ссылки работают (через ctrl кликать по модуль "discord">"client">"aiohttp", но модуль все также не находит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почему-то, версия питона, решила измениться с последней на предыдущую, из-за чего discord не запускался на НОВОЙ версии, тк пакеты он все равно брал не из директории проекта, а из директории интерпретатора. Переключился на раннюю версию питона и заработало, потом принудительно скачал на новую версию и также заработало.